# Cannot hide fields and populate field based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to:
1. Hide and display fields based on SELECT a field
2. Populate a field based on check boxes
However neither is working.  Both were based on working solutions from others.  The only difference I can think of is that I am using TABLE to format them.  But I don't know if that makes a difference.

The HTML code:

```
<form method="POST">
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" /><b>Business:</b>
        <td><select id="business" name="business" >
            <option value="1">Sell</option>
            <option value="2">Buy</option>
            <option value="3">Both</option>
            <option value="4">Trade</option>
            <option value="5">Freight</option>
            <option value="6">Customs</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        </tr>    

        <div id="freight">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Service Type:</b></td>
        <td><select name="type">
            <option value="1">Air Cargo</option>
            <option value="2">Couriers</option>
            <option value="3">Freight Forwarder</option>
            </select>
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Tollfree Number:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tollfree" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </div>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><b>Your Email Address:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
                    </tr>
    <div id="customs">
    <tr>
        <td /><b>Services:</b>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="ACA - Air Cargo Agent" />ACA - Air Cargo Agent<br /> 
            <input type="checkbox" value="AFF - Air Freight Forwarder" />AFF - Air Freight Forwarder<br /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    </div>
            <tr>
            <td><b>Products/Services:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="products" /></td>
            </tr>   
    <div id="brand">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Brand Names:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="brands" /></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    </table>
</form>
```

The jQuery code for doing these:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
    $('input[name=products]').val(
        $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join(',')
    );
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); 
    $("#business").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#business").val() == 1 || ($("#business").val() == 2 || ($("#business").val() == 3)
        $("#brand").show();
        $("#freight").hide();
        $("#customs").hide();
    else
        if ($("#business").val() == 5)
            $("#brand").hide();
            $("#freight").show();
            $("#customs").show();
        else
            if ($("#business").val() == 6)
                $("#brand").hide();
                $("#freight").hide();
                $("#customs").show();   
            else
                $("#brand").hide();
                $("#freight").hide();
                $("#customs").hide();               
}
```

For example when you select "Sell", "Buy" or "Both" (in Business), the SERVICE TYPE and TOLLFREE NUMBER fields are supposed to be hidden, as well as SERVICES field. They are wrapped in DIV id "freight" and "customs" and supposed to be invisible.  But they are not.  All fields are shown regardless.

Second problem is if you select Customs (in Business) the Services field which is composed of checkboxes is supposed to be shown and when click on the check boxes, the value in these checkboxes is supposed to populate the Products/Services field.  It is not doing that either.

Here is the jsfiddle for this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/5SArB/571/

which is based on the working version of both

jsfiddle.net/5SArB/  (toggle fields based on form values)

and

jsfiddle.net/dTrVt/  (populate input field based on checkbox id values)

I am pulling my hair on this and just can't understand why it is not working.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the code, the first of which is that the javascript is poorly formed.

1. You can't write if statements without curly braces if they take more than one line
2. The first if statement in toggleFields is missing some parentheses

Once you get that fixed, the other problem concerns the formation of your html table. Don't wrap the table rows with divs, since that's improper html table structure. Instead, you might take out the divs, and assign the "id"s to the table rows instead. Essentially what you would be doing then is showing/hiding table rows rather than showing/hiding divs containing the table rows.

The resulting HTML would be then:

```
<tr id="freight">
    ...
</tr>
```

Rather than:

```
<div id="freight">
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SArB/582/) with the proposed changes.

Hope that helps!

Edit: In case somebody comes across this in the future, the problem was a simple issue with load order -- the document wasn't ready when the click event was bound. The solution is as simple as moving the click event inside the document.ready callback.

Comment: Thank you Mark, this is great help.  There is still a little problem.  The Tollfree Number also belongs to part of the "freight" div before.  When I add the id="freight" for the tollfree row as well, it won't hide it. jsfiddle.net/5SArB/575/

Comment: @Jack Oh I missed that, my bad. The reason you can't add id to both rows is because id's are meant to be unique. So you could instead swap out the id for a class, such as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SArB/580/). Hopefully that works for you :)

Comment: As you can see I am not much of a programmer.  I don't know much of css nor javascript.  I implemented in on our beta site.  The toggle is working but the checkboxes still not working.  It's driving me insane.  I would provide a user id and pw to access it but don't want to do it publicly because it's not yet public.  How do I give it to you?  I am new to this site.

Comment: @Jack No worries, I completely understand your frustration. Is there a reproduction of your error somewhere? It looks like the fiddle in your original question isn't updated (I still see div's around tr's)

Comment: I just used your fiddle and it works fine.  But when I implemented in on actual beta site, it won't work. :(  I don't see any error produced it just wont populate the checkboxes into the field.  I couldn't use the fiddle for this because the original code is mixed with Coldfusion.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you have syntax errors and you can't have `div` as a child of `table`.

In the `if...else if` statements you are missing the block definitions...
Also assign the ids to the `tr` instead of nesting it in a `div`.

Also the code can be simplified as

```js
$(':checkbox').click(function () {
    $('input[name=products]').val($(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(','));
});
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#business").change(toggleFields).change();
});

function toggleFields() {
    var el = $('#business option:selected').data('el'),
        els = el ? '#'+el.split(/,\s*/).join(', #'):'';
    
    var $els =els? $(els).show():$();
    $('.bussiness-field').not($els).hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Toggle fields based on form values</h1>

<form method="POST">
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" /><b>Business:</b>

            <td>
                <select id="business" name="business">
                    <option value="1" data-el="brand">Sell</option>
                    <option value="2" data-el="brand">Buy</option>
                    <option value="3" data-el="brand">Both</option>
                    <option value="4">Trade</option>
                    <option value="5" data-el="freight, customs">Freight</option>
                    <option value="6" data-el="customs">Customs</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="freight" class="bussiness-field">
            <td><b>Service Type:</b>

            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="type">
                    <option value="1">Air Cargo</option>
                    <option value="2">Couriers</option>
                    <option value="3">Freight Forwarder</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Tollfree Number:</b>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="tollfree" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><b>Your Email Address:</b>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="customs" class="bussiness-field">
            <td /><b>Services:</b>

            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="ACA - Air Cargo Agent" />ACA - Air Cargo Agent
                <br />
                <input type="checkbox" value="AFF - Air Freight Forwarder" />AFF - Air Freight Forwarder
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Products/Services:</b>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="products" size="40" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="brand" class="bussiness-field">
            <td><b>Brand Names:</b>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="brands" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun.  Your answer works too.  I would vote up for you but since I am new, I need to work my way up before I can vote.  Your code definitely is far more advanced than my understanding of javascript which is almost next to none. :-)